# Is it possible to initialize variable with same name but different numbers at the end?

Tags: c++, c++17

In a situation I have to define some variables where I have control on parts of the variable names (like `var` below).

```
float var1, var2, var3....;
```

But I do not have any control on the numbers that they will take. (This is because these `var*` I am producing from some other code where everytime I compile, these numbers at the end will be different).

My question: **Is there any way to define these variables a priori?**

Like (lets say that the `var*` are generated within `var100`.)

```
float var1,...,var100;
```

without explicitly typing each and every `var*`.
It would have been much better to have array in this position, but is there any way to do this in this way?

Comment: You're looking for a data structure, like a map, vector, or array

Comment: Even if you would achieve that, you'd still have to type every single variable name in order to use it... `std::array` or `std::vector` is a way to go

Comment: You should really be using an array or vector for this.

Comment: "*This is because these `var*` I am producing from some other code where everytime I compile, these numbers at the end will be different*" You must be employing some kind of code generation process, so why can't that process also generate *definitions* for these variables?

Comment: why you use off-site code generation in first place? C++ is quite good at doing it with language tools. With C++11 you have tuples, with C++14 you have structured binding.

Comment: `float* varArray[] = {&var1, &var2, &var3... &var100};` seems closest, but if they're different each time then even that won't work.

Comment: @MooingDuck generate macro with those names, put it into a tuple? or map XD

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, this is the option I am exploring (which is not in C++ ). It would be much better to have this as some vector or array like all of you are suggesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do know the bounds and you do not mind leaving unused variables, you *can* play with the preprocessor to generate them. For instance:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>

#define ONE_FLOAT(z, n, x) float var##n;

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(100, ONE_FLOAT, x)
```

<sub>Note 1: implementing `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` by hand is out of the scope of this answer.</sub>

<sup>Note 2: of course, arrays and similar solutions are the proper ones, but the question disallows those.</sup>

---

<sub>*Edit: this was written before knowing that the bounds where known ahead of time.*</sub>

No. You are asking how to define variables without knowing their name, which is impossible.

It does not make sense either, because if you don't know their names, you cannot do anything with them either. It is like trying to write equations with symbols without knowing what the symbols are.

You will need some kind of code generation script that will fill them in for you and then possibly `#include` them in the right place. Same for the places you actually use the variables.

Comment: You are right. This is indeed not nice. Putting a ‘#include’ with the names generated by some external script would be the last option. Btw similar feature is available in Form (although a symbolic manipulation system based on C) like ‘Symbol var1,...,var100;’ will declare all ‘var’ within this range.

Comment: @Boogeyman Oh, so you do know the bounds then? In that case, you can use the preprocessor -- see edit.